# Why does Stack Overflow get a F in the Add Expires Headers category from YSlow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, performance, yslow

Stack Overflow's main page gets good grades in YSlow except for an F for **Add Expires Headers**. I know that SE team members are obsessed with performance. Why don't they put far expiration dates in the headers by configuring IIS?

Comment: Why are people closing this??  This is a legitimate technical question

Comment: It's likely getting an "F" because it has a Vary:* header.

Comment: We're voting to move it to meta, where it belongs, as it's about the site itself.

Comment: @cHao - but thats just a coincidence . . i am fine moving it to meta (can i do this myself??) but it seems like it could belong in either

Comment: F stands for *fabulous*

Comment: See also "Yahoo's Problems Are Not Your Problems": http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/yslow-yahoos-problems-are-not-your-problems.html

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82225/google-chrome-audit-approval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YSlow gives me grade D for Expires headers,

[image]

As you can see there, all of those sites are outside stackoverflow network.

And also those are ads, and site stats sites, so expires headers are no much meaningful for such sites.